# Why does $E|X|=\infty$ imply $EX=\infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, absolute-convergence

In Casella and Berger Example 2.2.4(Cauchy mean), in trying to show that Cauchy random variable $X$ has no mean, the authors prove that $E|X|=\infty$. Since we want to prove that $EX=\infty$, it has to be that  $E|X|=\infty$ implies $EX=\infty$. I'm wondering why $E|X|=\infty$ implies $EX=\infty$? A proof or a reference are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: In general it doesn't imply $E(X)=\infty$. It only implies that the definition of $E(X)$ doesn't assign it a value.

Comment: The Cauchy distribution has no $E[X]$, $\infty$ or otherwise. $=\infty$ doesn't mean "doesn't exist".

Comment: @user85667 Thanks! Why is it reasonable not to assign a value to $E(X)$ when $E|X|=\infty$.

Comment: That $E[|X|]=\infty$ isn't _the reason why_ $E[X]$ doesn't exist; for some other distributions, you get one result without the other.

Comment: The quality of being undefined is not an absolute property. $E(X)$ is defined as a Lebesgue integral and this only assigns a real value when $E|X|<\infty$. It assigns the value $\infty$, when $E(X^-)<\infty$ and $E(X^+)=\infty$. Depending on your purposes, you could use some other definition that does assign a value to $E(X)$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks! Could you give some examples?

Comment: @ExcitedSnail A non-negative variable of infinite mean has defined, but infinite, mean for its modulus. For example, the PDF $1/x^2$ on $[1,\,\infty)$ has $E[X]=E[|X|]=\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not imply that. But note that in Definition 2.2.1 of the same book, the author's *define* $Eg(X)$ not to exist if $E|g(X)| = \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! I see this one. Why is it reasonable  to $E(X)$ as "not exist" when $E|X|=\infty$?

Comment: What @user85667 said. By definition of the expected value, $EX = E(X^{+}) - E(X^{-})$. So if *exactly one* of the components on the RHS is infinite, the integral will be infinite as well, which is not a real value. But $E|X| = E(X^{+}) + E(X^{-})$. So if $E|X| = \infty$, at least one component is infinite. In that case $EX$ is not assigned a real value. So if you are only interested in defining $EX$ when the integrals are real valued, $E|X| = \infty$ implies $EX$ does not exist.

Comment: I see. From this decomposition, it seems that $EX=\infty$ if and only if $E|X|=\infty$.